# Редирект htaccess или laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

есть две ссылки:

https://test.com/c_id=123&d=123

https://test.com/?c_id=123&d=123

Вторая ссылка работает правильно, а вот первая нет, нужно силами htaccess или laravel поставить вопрос в первую, но так, что бы он не ставился во вторую.

`RewriteRule ^/$ /?$ [R=301,L]`

Вроде как должен работать вот такой вариант, но тогда полностью ломается сайт.

P.S. Естественно параметры c_id=123&d=123 динамичные, всё время будут разные.

Answer (score 0):

В общем получилось разбить их по разным методам только с помощью laravel:

`Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\Redirect::class, 'index']);`

`Route::get('/{any}', [\App\Http\Controllers\Redirect::class, 'index2'])->where(['any' => '^[a-zA-Z0-9_=&]{1,50}$']);`

Пока не знаю насколько это решение правильное, но если найду что-то более подходящее дополню ответ.